# swift and Xcode - prevent tests running against a real device

Tags: swift, unit-testing, testing

so - I'm currently having to do a bit of cleanup - I am doing lots of stuff with HealthKit...  I have a bunch of tests that are "real" tests - but then I have a bunch where I'm using the test code to just generate values - because I usually test against the simulators, and if you want a graph, you need a whole bunch of historical values for instance.

so of course I hit the wrong button - and I just filled my actual real device with fake HealthKit data.   Fortunately it is tagged, so I'm currently building something to delete it all...

but is there a way of either identifying a test as "this should never run on a physical device" - or just detecting inside the test that I'm on a physical device and failing?

Comment: The standard test for simulator vs device doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know what the standard test is

Comment: Can you just mock out healthkit so you never edit its contents for real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this helpful:

[Target environment platform condition](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0190-target-environment-platform-condition.md)

You'd do something like this in your unit test:

```
    func testExample() throws {
        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
            // whatever your assertions are
        #else
            // doing nothing here
        #endif
    }
```

Comment: that''s _exactly_ what I was looking for - thanks!